# JS - Appending a logged sequence of numbers

Tags: javascript, string, append, sequence

I've made a sequence of numbers from 0 to 20 and I want to change the sequence so once it comes up with a multiple of 3 and 5 it logs 'FizzBuzz' to the terminal then carries on with the rest of the numbers up to 20. My problem is once I have changed the number to the string the rest of the terms in the sequence come up with NaN. I know the problem with my code is that I'm changing the number to a string and you cannot perform addition to a string which is why NaN comes up. I'm pretty new to this so any thoughts on how to do complete this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried using .append() but I'm pretty sure I'm using it incorrectly.

My code thus far;

```js
    var increment = function(number)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
        {
            console.log(number++)
            if ((number % 3 === 0) && (number % 5 === 0))
            {
                number = "FizzBuzz"
                console.log("FizzBuzz");
            }
            else if (number % 3 === 0)
            {
                console.log("Fizz");
            }
            else if (number % 5 === 0)
            {
                console.log("Buzz");
            }
            else
            {}
        }
    }
    increment(1)
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want to return something? Or display something?

Comment: Do you want to log the string and the number (i.e. "Fizz" and then 3), or just the string if it satisfies the condition (i.e. just "Fizz, then on to 4)?

Comment: is this a coding challenge / tutorial somewhere? i saw multiple "fizzbuzz" questions out there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would do it

```
var increment = function()
{
    for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++)
    {
        if ((i % 3 === 0) && (i % 5 === 0))
        {
            console.log("FizzBuzz");
        }
        else if (i % 3 === 0)
        {
            console.log("Fizz");
        }
        else if (i % 5 === 0)
        {
            console.log("Buzz");
        }
        else{
            console.log(i)
        }
    }
}
increment()
```

There's no need to pass the `number` parameter, since your `for` loop is already set to increment by 1 (`i++`).

Comment: As noted in the other answer, the reason you were having trouble was because you were setting `number` as a string, which there really wasn't a need for. If this answer works for you, please accept it (click the little checkmark).

Answer (score 2):

When you find a multiple of 3 and 5, you are setting `number` to `"FizzBuzz"`, which does not have a `++` operator. On the next iteration, you call `++` on `number`, which is now `"FizzBuzz"`, so it logs `NaN`.

If you don't set `number` to `"FizzBuzz"` it should work fine.